# The relation of correlation coefficient of the sum of two vectors.

Tags: statistics, vectors, correlation

Does the correlation coefficient of the sum of two vectors between the correlation coefficient of each of them. Suppose I have three vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3$. The correlation coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_2$ is $c_1$, the correlation coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_3$ is $c_2$, the correlation coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_2+x_3$ is $c_3$. Can I state that $$\min(c_1,c_2)<c_3<\max(c_1,c_2)$$

Answer (score 1):

For a short answer, no, you couln't conclude that. For a simple example, let:
    $$ x_{1}=(1,2,3,4)^{T} $$
    $$ x_{2}=(0,3,2,5)^{T} $$
$$  x_{3}=(2,1,4,3)^{T} $$
It's easy to compute: $c_{1}=0.8682$, $c_{2}=0.6$, $c_{3}=1$.

Comment: Is there any relation between them?